# Swift struct extensions: 'Cannot convert return expression of type <type> to return type <type>'

Tags: swift, struct, swift2

Let's say you have the following structs and protocols:

```
struct Ticket {
    var items: [TicketItem] = []
}

struct TicketItem {
}

protocol DisplayableTicket {
    var displayedItems: [DisplayableTicketItem] { get }
}

protocol DisplayableTicketItem {}
```

Now, if I were to extend those structs like so:

```
extension Ticket: DisplayableTicket {
    var displayedItems: [DisplayableTicketItem] {
        return self.items
    }
}

extension TicketItem: DisplayableTicketItem {}
```

I get the following error on the line `return self.items`:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[TicketItem]' to return type 'DisplayableTicketItem'
```

If I change the type of Ticket and TicketItem to `class`, I don't get an error. Why can't the Ticket struct contain an array of TicketItem structs and be extended as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
extension Ticket: DisplayableTicket {
    var displayedItems: [DisplayableTicketItem] {
        return self.items.map{$0 as DisplayableTicketItem}
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives you a practical solution. I admit it doesn't answer the "why" question, but that's because there is no answer. It's just how Swift works (or doesn't); array-of-protocol is not really a first-class type with the same syntactic-sugar shortcuts as array-of-real-type. Basically the same as my point here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself